# How can make get confused without .PHONY targets?

Tags: makefile

I'm reading the `make` manual and I ended up on this paragraph:

> Here is how we could write a make rule for cleaning our example
>   editor:
>
> ```
> clean:
>     rm edit $(objects)
> ```
>
> In practice, we might want to write the rule in a somewhat more
>   complicated manner to handle unanticipated situations. We would do
>   this:
>
> ```
> .PHONY : clean clean :
>     -rm edit $(objects)
> ```
>
> This prevents make from getting confused by an actual file called
>   clean and causes it to continue in spite of errors from rm. (See Phony
>   Targets, and Errors in Recipes.)

I understand that `clean` target does not refer to a file on the filesystem but how make can getting confused if I omit the `.PHONY` declaration on a target that should be declared as `.PHONY`?

I would see an example that confuses the `make` command.

P.S.: what does the minus symbol before `rm` command represent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's test this. Fire your terminal of choice, navigate to your directory of choice and then create a new directory (to hold the test files). I chose `so-27204300`:

```
$ mkdir so-27204300
$ cd so-27204300
```

Now create a simple `Makefile` without the .PHONY annotation. I'll only show the contents:

```
clean:
    echo "Clean is executing"
```

Execute the `make` command, you should get the following output:

```
$ make
echo "Clean is executing"
Clean is executing
```

Now, create a `clean` file (`touch clean`) and execute `make` again. You'll get

```
$ make
make: `clean' is up to date.
```

because there is a file `clean` newer than the output of the target `clean`. Add `.PHONY clean` to the `Makefile` so it will read

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    echo "Clean is executing"
```

Now, even with the file `clean` in your directory, `make` will execute the target

```
$ make
echo "Clean is executing"
Clean is executing
```

---

Regarding your PS: change this `Makefile` so that it reads:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm test
    echo "Done"
```

As you see, there's no `-` there but also there is no `test` file in the current directory. Running `make` will give you

```
$ make
rm test
rm: cannot remove ‘test’: No such file or directory
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

And no output from `echo`. If the `clean` target was a prerequisite to another target then because of this error the other target would not have been built either.

Adding a `-` so that the `Makefile` reads:

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm test
    echo "Done"
```

solves this problem:

```
$ make
rm test
rm: cannot remove ‘test’: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
echo "Done"
Done
```

For `rm` you can also use `-f` to let it stop complaining on errors. But there are other commands which don't have a silencer of errors argument.

---

If you want to hide the printing of command being executed you can use `@` instead of `-`.